# Simplify $\cos 1^\circ + \cos 3^\circ + \cdots+ \cos 43^\circ$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

I am currently working on a problem and reduced part of the equations down to

$$\cos(1^\circ)+\cos(3^\circ)+\cdots+\cos(39^\circ)+\cos(41^\circ)+\cos(43^\circ)$$

How can I calculate this easily using the product-to-sum formula for $\cos(x)+\cos(y)$?

Comment: It is an abstract duplicate, but I do not agree about closing it. Since it is an *abstract* duplicate, not an *exact* or *almost exact* one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is to multiply the whole sum by $2\sin 1^\circ$. Since:
$$ 2\sin 1^\circ \cos 1^{\circ} = \sin 2^\circ - \sin 0^\circ,$$
$$ 2\sin 1^\circ \cos 3^{\circ} = \sin 4^\circ - \sin 2^\circ,$$
$$\ldots $$
$$ 2\sin 1^\circ \cos 43^{\circ} = \sin 44^\circ - \sin 42^\circ,$$
by adding these identites we get that the original sum $S$, multiplied by $2\sin 1^\circ$, equals $\sin 44^\circ$.

This just gives $S=\color{red}{\frac{\sin 44^\circ}{2\sin 1^{\circ}}}.$

---

Footnote. Such sum must be greater than $\frac{44\sqrt{2}}{\pi}$, but not greater than $\frac{44\sqrt{2}}{\pi}+\frac{\pi}{22\sqrt{2}}$, by a Riemann sum $+$ concavity argument.

Comment: Very nice! I've never seen that before.

Comment: @JackDAurizio: How would I apply that to this problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100721/prove-that-nsinn-is-cot-1-degree?

Comment: @MathyPerson: in such a case, multiply by $2\sin 1^°$ and use the Briggs formula *twice*. It is not much different from proving that $$\sum_{n\geq 1}n z^n = \frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$$ for any $z$ such that $|z|<1$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: I haven't learned the Briggs formula yet. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: @MathyPerson: the Briggs formula is the sum-product formula.

Answer (score 1):

let $S = \cos(1^\circ)+\cos(3^\circ)+.....+\cos(39^\circ)+\cos(41^\circ)+\cos(43^\circ).$ then 
\begin{align} 2S\sin 1^\circ &= 2\cos 1^\circ \sin 1^\circ + 2 \cos 3^\circ \sin 1^\circ+\cdots + 2 \cos 43^\circ \sin 1^\circ \\
& = (\sin 2^\circ - \sin 0^\circ)+(\sin 4^\circ - \sin 2^\circ ) + \cdots 
+(\sin 44^\circ- \sin 42^\circ))\\
& = \sin44^\circ 
\end{align}

therefore $$ S = \dfrac{\sin 44^\circ}{ 2\sin 1^\circ} $$